# Voting with less than 125 reputation points

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, down-votes, privileges

I have found that if I upvote an answer, it gets upvoted, but if I downvote I receive a message that the vote is hidden until I have sufficient reputation points.

Here's an example from an answer on [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) - on which I have [101 reputation points](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/56656/jbithell).

If I upvote:

[image: Upvote]

It simply gets upvoted - isn't that nice!

The trouble is if I downvote an answer, I get a message saying my vote is hidden until I have 125 reputation points:

[image: Downvote]

And here is an example of a question on [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/), on which I have [113 reputation points](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/14397/jbithell):

[image: Upvote]

[image: Downvote]

So either this is a straightforward network-wide bug, or this is a Stack Exchange policy to hide downvotes from users with less than 125 reputation points - in which case perhaps the wording of the message is ambiguous?

Comment: you think it's a bug because you think you just need x reputation to vote, but in fact the rep needed to upvote and downvote are different

Comment: @KateGregory, the current message for downvote causes confusion “You need at least 125 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.” , but should be “You need at least 125 reputation to DOWN vote, but your feedback has been recorded.”

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, it is not a bug - you receive the ['vote down'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) privilege at 125 reputation. In the meantime, the system does record your 'downvotes' (for anonymous feedback, as @NathanTuggy mentions), but once you reach 125 reputation nothing happens to these vote attempts.

The popup text is misleading, that's why people have asked to [change it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326060/change-the-wording-of-thank-you-for-your-feedback-when-a-user-below-125-re) - and this feature request seems to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) as of [today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327213/4751173).

Comment: Note that the downvote records are stored separately, as anonymous feedback.

Comment: Shouldn't it be [status-bydesign]?

Comment: I don't think this feature is "complete"... often I'll downvote something and later rescind it without upvoting, which appears impossible for users below 125 reputation.  Is the sub-125 "anonymous feedback" downvoting effectively a placebo?

Comment: The message is still misleading: “You need at least 125 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.” , but should be “You need at least 125 reputation to  DOWN vote, but your feedback has been recorded.”