# Do posts in the first answers and first questions queues age out?

Tags: support, review, new-users, time

Do review items in the *First questions* and *First answers* queues age out of the queues?

I tried finding this info in [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538) but it doesn't say. Neither could I find the info in [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390) It also doesn't say in the Help Center [How do I use the First questions queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-first-questions) or in [How do I use the First answers queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-first-answers)

I didn't find any mention in [Improving the Review Queues - Project overview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346901) or any of its subsequent posts. I think this has also not been mentioned in [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013).

The reason I'm asking is because because on SO after 13 days of the new *First questions* queue there were 25k reviews, but there are 9.5k pending reviews. Meaning at this rate there would be 266k pending reviews within one year.

**EDIT:** Random Person shared an older post in the comments [When is a review task "completed" or "invalidated"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190581) that lists some rules that predated present *Review Queue* redesign.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Review tasks in both *First questions* and *First answers* are invalidated in any of the following cases:

- 14 days elapse since the `CreationDate` of the post
- The score of the post is >= 3
- For answers, if the post owner rep goes over 125
- Post deleted
- Question closed

These are the default values, currently used across the network. They can all be customized per site if appropriate.

Comment: Why is the 250 rep threshold implemented only for answers and not questions?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I was wondering that myself when writing this, and anticipating your question, am already raising the question internally. Might just be an oversight, in which case the same will be added to questions. I'll follow up here.

Comment: Just to make sure, once a review item is invalidated, it's final, right? (No way it will become available again)

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 that review task will not come back. A new review task could be created for FQ based on feedback from the Triage queue, or if item is edited and still qualifies for the queue.

Comment: Any further follow-up on that question two weeks later?

Comment: Is it 125 on answers [because 125 is needed to downvote an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280780/282094), (but that's different on different sites: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) - so, presumably the idea was for reviewers to be able to review until the OP obtained the downvote privilege; it shouldn't be a *flat* 125, but instead a variable equal to the site's DV privilege requirement.

Comment: 125 because it is over the association bonus, but not by too much. If you earned 100 on another site and then 25 more on this site, we're assuming you don't need extra supervision with questions and answers anymore.

Comment: Do these criteria also apply for *Late answers*?