# "Other action" in "First answers" doesn't fully complete the review

Tags: discussion, status-completed, review

Following community feedback to the recent changes in review queues, as [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036/616624) (and some other, very similar requests on that post), the UI team have now added an "Other action" radio-button in the "First answers" and "First questions" queues, which allows one to complete the review when an action like voting (up or down) on the post, adding a custom comment or flagging has been taken.

First, I would like to thank the developer team for taking on board the community's concerns and adding this option.

However, it appears that this does not *actually* fully complete the review – the post stays in the queue, so that another reviewer has to take (it would seem) one of the three original, 'primary' actions.

Here are two reviews that I made earlier today: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/29819144) needed a second review, because I added a custom comment and clicked "Other action"; but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/29819540) was completed after my single review, because I clicked "Share feedback" to add a canned Community comment. (IMHO, there is little to distinguish between the two actions I took in these reviews.)

Is this "by design" or is it an oversight? If the former, then how many such "Other action" reviews are needed to pop the post from the queue? (Or will only one of the first three actions actually finish off the process?)

---

*As an aside, I have noticed that taking such "Other action" is sufficient to pass (or fail?) an audit: I flagged a "known bad" audit today and passed ("Share feedback" would also have passed).*

Comment: So.. a canned comment that maybe kind of fits is fine, but a carefully crafted one needs a second opinion? :D

Comment: @Unconsidered actually using system generated comments will [still require other reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369545#comment1234040_369545). See also the answer to [Do posts in the first answers and first questions queues age out?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369758/665544)

Comment: Also after one picks share feedback one is supposed to continue by clicking on "submit" even though it doesn't submit and one doesn't want to submit, one wants the further steps before (possibly) submitting. Bad design.

Comment: @bad_coder That's incorrect, the "Share Feedback" option does indeed complete the review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/29779477

Comment: This was already raised in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369545, which unfortunately didn’t seem to receive any staff attention.

Comment: Confirmed that this does _not_, in fact, happen in Late Answers: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/29833591 That makes it seem even more like a simple oversight to me.

Comment: Just ran across a post with _12_ "Reviewed" notices! https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Zmv.png ([Link to review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/29782281))

Comment: @zcoop98 OK - Challenge announced: Any advance on 12?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I fixed the issue and the fix should be live later today. It was indeed a simple oversight - my oversight, in fact. Thanks for reporting this bug, please let me know if you continue experiencing any issues in the next couple of days.

Comment: Seems good - checked a few "Other action" reviews just now and they *do* now complete the review. Thanks.